# Sql loop through the values on a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

first off, noob alert! :))

I need to construct a query that runs on many tables. The tables vary on name just on the last digits as per client code. The thing is, the values that change aren't sequential so looping as in i=1,2,3,... does not work. A possible solution would be to have those values on a given field on an other table.

Here is the code for the first two clients 015 and 061. The leading zero(s) must are essential.

```
SELECT LnMov2017015.CConta, RsMov2017015.DR, RsMov2017015.NInt, "015" AS CodCli
FROM LnMov2017015 INNER JOIN RsMov2017015 ON LnMov2017015.NReg = RsMov2017015.NReg
WHERE (((LnMov2017015.CConta)="6" And (LnMov2017015.CConta)="7") AND ((RsMov2017015.DR)=9999))

UNION SELECT LnMov2017061.CConta, RsMov2017061.DR, RsMov2017061.NInt, "061" AS CodCli
FROM LnMov2017061 INNER JOIN RsMov2017061 ON LnMov2017061.NReg = RsMov2017061.NReg
WHERE (((LnMov2017061.CConta)="6" And (LnMov2017061.CConta)="7") AND ((RsMov2017061.DR)=9999))

...
```

So for the first `SELECT` the table Name is **LnMov2017015**, the ending **015** being the value, the client code, that changes from table to table e.g. in the second `SELECT` the table name is LnMov2017061 (**061**) being what distinguishes the table.

For each client code there are two tables e.g. **LnMov2017015** and **RsMov2017015** (***LnMov2017061*** and **RsMov2017061** for the second set client shown).

Is there a way that I can build the SQL, based upon the example SQL above?

Does anyone have an idea for a solution? :)

Comment: could you describe the problem a bit more?

Comment: You probably need to look into dynamic SQL. A better long term option may be to put all customers in one table and use a field to distinguish between them

Comment: ^^ Exactly. This is terrible database design, and now you are paying the price for it. If I were you, I wouldn't waste any more time with workarounds and consolidate these tables into one single table.

Comment: Based on the comment from @JeffUK I was trying to think of a way of pulling in the `MSysObjects` table as a way to get the last two digits of the table names, something like `SELECT Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE LEFT(Name,5) IN ('LnMov','RsMov')`, but then the `FROM` clause needs updating for each table.  A single table, or maybe two - one for RsMove and one for LnMove would be the way to go based on the info given.

Comment: No question about the database design this is a solution to audit several db @ same time. The current option is to open an accounting app one client @ a time... but merging the DB into one isn't an option :(

Comment: but maybe merging them all together in a query is....

Comment: That will do :) thank you for your input. :) Is it possible to read the contents of an table not previously linked in ms-access directly with SQL?

Comment: Why not set links? How many tables? UNION may be only feasible approach.

Comment: Near 100 tables, that will change every year

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is possible to build a query object to read data in another db without establishing table link. Just tested and to my surprise it works. Example:

`SELECT * FROM [SoilsAgg] IN "C:\Users\Owner\June\DOT\Lab\Editing\ConstructionData.accdb";`

I was already using this structure in VBA to execute DELETE and UPDATE action statements.

Comment: It works great! But the DB is password protected. It is possible to enter the password in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found :)

Thank you all for your input.

Instead of linking 100 tables (password protected), I'll access them with SLQ

```
FROM Table2 IN '' ';database=C:\db\db2.mdb;PWD=mypwd'
```

And merge them all with a query, before any other thing!

Comment: By 'merge' you mean a UNION? There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines in a UNION.